# Additional radio button in a custom checkout field group that update a fee in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, radio-button, cart

This question is related *"[Update fee dynamically based on radio buttons in Woocommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457961/update-fee-dynamically-based-on-radio-buttons-in-woocommerce-checkout/49470265#49470265)"* answer, which works nicely.

Actually there is 2 radio buttons in the field group and I would like to add an additional one (so 3 radio buttons at all).

My question is I would like to add an additional radio button, but I am just not seeing/understanding where to add an additional option.

I have added an extra field in the 'options' array:
...........................................................................

```
'options' => array(
            'bag' => __('In a bag '.wc_price(3.00), $domain),
            'box' => __('In a gift box '.wc_price(9.00), $domain),
            'speedboat' => __('In a speedboat '.wc_price(20.00), $domain),
```

...........................................................................

However I am confused by this section:

...........................................................................

```
$packing_fee = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_packing' ); // Dynamic packing fee
    $fee = $packing_fee == 'box' ? 9.00 : 3.00;
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'Packaging fee', 'woocommerce' ), $fee );
```

........................................................................

I tried adding:-

```
$packing_fee = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_packing' ); // Dynamic packing fee
    $fee = $packing_fee == 'box' ? 9.00 : 3.00 :;
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'Packaging fee', 'woocommerce' ), $fee );
```

but I doubt I am doing it right.

Can somebody please guide me on how to do this please?

Comment: Sorry but I could not post in the original thread as I am a new member here.

Comment: p.s.- I meant to say:-

$packing_fee = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_packing' ); // Dynamic packing fee
    $fee = $packing_fee == 'box' ? 9.00 : 3.00 : 25.00 ;
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'Packaging fee', 'woocommerce' ), $fee );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your 3 radio button (3 options in the array) like:

```
'options' => array(
    'bag' => __('In a bag '.wc_price(3.00), $domain),
    'box' => __('In a gift box '.wc_price(9.00), $domain),
    'speedboat' => __('In a speedboat '.wc_price(20.00), $domain),
),
```

You will have to replace this original code:

```
$packing_fee = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_packing' ); // Dynamic packing fee
$fee = $packing_fee == 'box' ? 9.00 : 3.00;
$cart->add_fee( __( 'Packaging fee', 'woocommerce' ), $fee );
```

with the following (for a third option):

```
$packing_fee = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_packing' ); // Dynamic packing fee

if( $packing_fee === 'box' )
   $fee = 9.00; 
else if( $packing_fee === 'speedboat' ) 
   $fee = 20.00;
else
   $fee = 3.00;

$cart->add_fee( __( 'Packaging fee', 'woocommerce' ), $fee );
```

or this similar in a more compact way:

```
$packing_fee = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_packing' ); // Dynamic packing fee
$fee = $packing_fee === 'bag' ? 3.00 : ( $packing_fee === 'box' ? 9.00 : 20.00 );
$cart->add_fee( __( 'Packaging fee', 'woocommerce' ), $fee );
```

Both should work.

Comment: Thank you very much Loic, appreciate it much! Honestly am not familiar with the compact code, the if and else statements make it clear as daylight!