# How to add a radio button with price on product page? WordPress woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

How can to customize the product page to include an extract fee base on the user's choice. Something slimier to the attached photo with customize your order option on the product page not on checkout page. [image]

I have this code which display the radio buttons and option on the checkout but for some reason the fee is not being added to the total.

```
    // Part 1
// Display Radio Buttons
// Uses woocommerce_form_field()

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice' );

function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice() {

   $chosen = WC()->session->get('radio_chosen');
   $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? WC()->checkout->get_value('radio_choice') : $chosen;
   $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? 'no_option' : $chosen;

   $args = array(
   'type' => 'radio',
   'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
   'options' => array(
      'no_option' => 'No Option',
      'option_1' => 'Option 1 ($10)',
      'option_2' => 'Option 2 ($30)',
   ),
   'default' => $chosen
   );

   echo '<div id="checkout-radio">';
   echo '<h3>Customize Your Order!</h3>';
   woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_choice', $args, $chosen );
   echo '</div>';

}

// Part 2
// Add Fee and Calculate Total
// Based on session's "radio_chosen"

#2 Calculate New Total

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_fee', 20, 1 );

function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_fee( $cart ) {

  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

  $radio = WC()->session->get( 'radio_chosen' );

  if ( "option_1" == $radio ) {
   $fee = 10;
  } elseif ( "option_2" == $radio ) {
   $fee = 30;
  }

  $cart->add_fee( __('Option Fee', 'woocommerce'), $fee );

}

// Part 3
// Refresh Checkout if Radio Changes
// Uses jQuery

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_refresh' );

function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_refresh() {
if ( ! is_checkout() ) return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name=radio_choice]', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var p = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'woo_get_ajax_data',
                    'radio': p,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Part 4
// Add Radio Choice to Session
// Uses Ajax

add_action( 'wp_ajax_woo_get_ajax_data', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woo_get_ajax_data', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session' );

function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session() {
    if ( isset($_POST['radio']) ){
        $radio = sanitize_key( $_POST['radio'] );
        WC()->session->set('radio_chosen', $radio );
        echo json_encode( $radio );
    }
    die();
}
```

If I change the hook to add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice' );

The option buttons shows up on the check out page and it work fine, I assume some how I need to pass the option value from product page to the check out page

Comment: do you want to add radio buttons in product page or in checkout page?

Comment: If you are looking as per image and update the price in checkout page [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457961/update-fee-dynamically-based-on-radio-buttons-in-woocommerce-checkout/#answer-49470265) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to follows code snippets to achieve your work -

```
function add_custom_fees_before_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    $args = array(
        'type' => 'radio',
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
        'options' => array(
            '' => 'No Option',
            '10' => 'Option 1 ($10)',
            '30' => 'Option 2 ($30)',
        ),
        'default' => ''
    );
    ?>
    <div class="custom-fees-wrap">
        <label for="iconic-engraving"><?php _e( 'Customize Your Order!', 'textdomain' ); ?></label>
        <?php woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_fees', $args, '' ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_custom_fees_before_add_to_cart', 99 );


function save_value_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    $custom_fees = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'custom_fees' );

    if ( empty( $custom_fees ) ) {
        return $cart_item_data;
    }

    $cart_item_data['custom_fees'] = $custom_fees;

    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_value_add_cart_item_data', 99, 3 );

function calculate_add_cart_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    foreach( $cart_items as $key => $item ) { 
        if( !isset( $item['custom_fees'] ) && empty( $item['custom_fees'] ) ) continue;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Custom fees', 'textdomain'), $item['custom_fees'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'calculate_add_cart_fee', 99 );
```