# Hide element if checkbox is not checked in Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using JavaScrip to show/hide a certain element if a certain checkbox is checked.
In my case, if the "Freight forwarding" checkbox is not checked, I would like to hide deposit payment options.

[image]

I have added deposit.js in my child theme and enqueued it by adding the following code in functions.php

```
function load_hide_deposit_script() {
  if( is_page(98) ) {
    //script location - child theme//
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js-file', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/deposit.js');
  }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_hide_deposit_script');
```

I checked developer tools and the script is loaded successfully.

Based on [How to show/hide an element on checkbox checked/unchecked states using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307323/how-to-show-hide-an-element-on-checkbox-checked-unchecked-states-using-jquery)

I have used two approaches:

```
function valueChanged()
    {
        if($('.input-checkbox.thwcfe-input-field').is(":checked"))   
            $(".cart-wcdpp-fields.order-total").show();
        else
            $(".cart-wcdpp-fields.order-total").hide();
    }
```

and

```
$(".cart-wcdpp-fields.order-total").hide();
$(".input-checkbox.thwcfe-input-field").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".cart-wcdpp-fields.order-total").show(300);
    } else {
        $(".cart-wcdpp-fields.order-total").hide(200);
    }
});
```

So far I haven't achieved desired result with these codes.

What could be the problem?

Link to the shop page (testing site) - https://siakurjers.wpengine.com/shop/

To check the functionality please add a product to the cart and visit the checkout page.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ruudolfs/wrved1po/18/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two components (checkbox and deposit options) are implemented by 3rd party plugins.

I am not sure why JS in the question did not do the trick.

Based on [Calculate fee from cart totals (subtotal + shipping) without adding it to order total value in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69203103/calculate-fee-from-cart-totals-subtotal-shipping-without-adding-it-to-order/), I used a PHP function with jQuery. It was inserted in the functions.php file.

```
// Show/hide deposit options

function action_wp_footer() {
    // Only on checkout
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        // Selector
        var my_input = 'input[name=forwarding]';
        var my_deposit = '#my_id_field';
        
        // Show or hide
        function show_or_hide() {
            if ( $( my_input ).is(':checked') ) {
                return $( my_deposit ).show();
            } else {
                return $( my_deposit ).hide();               
            }           
        }
        
        // Default
        $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
            show_or_hide();
        });
        
        // On change
        $( 'form.checkout' ).change(function() {
            show_or_hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer', 10, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, in [How to show/hide an element on checkbox checked/unchecked states using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307323/how-to-show-hide-an-element-on-checkbox-checked-unchecked-states-using-jquery) the `$(".ItemName").` and then assign the parameter "hide".

Try add a name to the Tr item and then try it.
It would be better if you can show some code with JSfiddle or directly in the question.

Comment: I added a JSfiddle link. By the way, these two elements are implemented by 3rd party plugins. Elements were copied from page source and pasted into JSfiddle.